# Franz Liszt Liebestraum No. 3 Bar 17 Roman Numeral Analysis

Tags: theory, chords, analysis, roman-numerals

I'm going through Liszt's Liebestraum No. 3 in Ab M.... in bar 17, I don't know how to mark the A natural chord. It's either a #1 or the song has modulated to the natural minor, in which case it would be a natural ii.

I feel like I can't call it a flat 2 due to the notation. What would you guys put there?

[edit: it would be a ii in the natural minor, not a iii. Again, I drink when looking at scores]

Comment: [Link](http://imslp.org/wiki/Liebestr%C3%A4ume,_S.541_(Liszt,_Franz)). Measure 17 is measure 2 of line 5 in the third link. There's no A♮ chord in that measure.

Comment: Luke, I'm not sure you linked to the right song. The score for the Liebestraum in Ab Maj can be found here: [link](http://www.free-scores.com/download-sheet-music.php?pdf=503) Admittedly, I was pretty drunk when I posted this question, but it's definitely a root position A ♮ chord - or else I'm losing my mind, haha.

Comment: I've also found our problem. You were referencing the third section of the piece. It is found in my version on page 13. Measure 17 is the third measure of that page in my version. And yes, there was an A minor chord in root position there. I've edited your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 7):

The chords should be notated as a modulation in measures 14-18. Liszt is using secondary dominant sequences. I have created a crude diagram to explain the sequencing. Chords in Brackets that are on top of each other are the same chords, just expressed in their respective key signatures.

```
AbMaj: I-vi-[V/vi] 
       CMaj:[  I ]-vi-[V/vi]
                 EMaj:[  I ]-vi-[V/vi]
```

I have also attached an image of the excerpt with my own analysis.

[image: Liebestraum No. 3 m.15-18]

Liszt playfully dances between the I-vi of each key and rounds himself back to G#(AbMaj.)

So in conclusion the A minor chord your referring to should be marked as **CMaj: vi**